# Can't use like button with ajax for each post in tape of posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, posts

So, i got a like button for every post. But my ajax catch event only for new one post. 
Please explain me why ajax does not make it for every post in tape. And how to fix it.

Here is an ajax code.

```
{% block jquery %}
  $("#po-like").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          url: $("#po-like-href").attr('href'),
          success: function(){
          },
          error: function(response, error){
          }
       })
  });
{% endblock %}
```

Here is mine tape of posts.

```
{% for post in tape %}
    ...
    {{ post.text }}
    ...
    <a id="po-like-href" href="/like_post/{{ post.id }}/">
        <img id="po-like"  src="{% static "" %}"/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

All others posts's like buttons work as if there is no ajax at all. If I click on them page reloads and number of likes changes

Comment: It's because of same `id's` in all `a` tags. You can have only one **uniq #id** in a html page. Instead you can change it to `.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of same `id's` in all `a` tags. You can have only one **uniq #id** in a html page. Instead you can change it to `.class`.

```
   {% block jquery %}
      $(".po-like").click(function(event){
          //changing #id to .class
          //added the below line
          var img = $(this);
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              url: img.parent().attr('href'),
              success: function(){
              },
              error: function(response, error){
              }
           })
      });
    {% endblock %}
{% for post in tape %}
    ...
    {{ post.text }}
    ...
    //changing #id to .class
    <a class="po-like-href" href="/like_post/{{ post.id }}/">
        <img class="po-like"  src="{% static "" %}"/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hehe, now it changes only last post's likes number even if i click on another posts's likes. But its cool at least it works not only with last post

Comment: Now it should work fine, as previously you were not getting the href of the clicked image's parent. So, using `$(this)` (which is that particular element which is clicked) solves the issue. Check the updated code above.

Comment: Hehe, looks like count number of likes becomes even a greater problem then like post XD

Comment: Where are you displaying number of likes count in the code?

Comment: Here is a link for the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040354/cant-change-number-of-likes-for-post-in-tape-with-ajax-when-click-like-button/38041012?noredirect=1#comment63541636_38041012