# Can't change number of likes for post in tape with ajax, when click like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, posts

I am trying to learn django and a bit more.
Got a problem with counting number of likes for every post in tape. Problem is that I can not get id of post. 
If I refresh page, count of likes changes. But to make it changing with ajax is real problem.
Please explain me how make changing likes count for every post in tape, if click like button.

Ajax code.

```
{% block jquery %}

function updatePostLikesCount(){
    var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count")
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/like_post/{{ post.id }}/post_likes_count/",
        success: function(data){
            postlikescount.html(data.count);
        },
        error: function(response, error){
        }
    })
}

$(".post-like").click(function(event){
    var img = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: img.parent().attr('href'),
        success: function(){
            updatePostLikesCount();
        },
        error: function(response, error){
        }
    })
});

{% endblock %}
```

Here is tape of posts.

```
{% for post in tape %}
    ...
    {{ post.text }}
    ...
    <a href="/like_post/{{ post.id }}/">
        <img class="post-like"  src="{% static "" %}"/>
    </a>

            <span class="post-likes-count" >
                {{ post.like.liked_users.count }}
            </span>

{% endfor %}
```

Here is a view that count post's likes

```
def post_likes_count(request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
        like = Like.objects.get(post_id=post_id)
        if like.liked_users.count == None:
            count = 0
        else:
            count = LikeTimestamp.objects.filter(like_id=like.id).count()
        return JsonResponse({
            'count': count,
        })
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Else I tried to reload an element of page with likes , but was defeated :-)

Comment: From where are you getting {{post.id}} value, please let the page reload and  then right click on the page and check if the {{post.id}} is replaced by the actual id, this is just to confirm before I suggest a solution.

Comment: Hmmm... There is no problem with id in `$(".post-like").click(function(event){`
there is a problem with `function updatePostLikesCount(){`   and   `url: "/like_post/{{ post.id }}/post_likes_count/",`
it trying to send this url `url: "/like_post//post_likes_count/",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
{% block jquery %}
    function updatePostLikesCount(postlikescount){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/like_post/"+postlikescount.data().id+"/post_likes_count/",
            success: function(data){
                alert('class is '+postlikescount.parent().find('.post-likes-count').attr('class'));
                postlikescount.parent().find('.post-likes-count').html(data.count).show();
                alert('likes count '+data.count);
            },
            error: function(response, error){
            }
        })
    }

    $(".post-like").click(function(event){
        var img = $(this);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: img.parent().attr('href'),
            success: function(){
                var like = img.parent();
                updatePostLikesCount(like);
            },
            error: function(response, error){
            }
        })
    });
{% endblock %}
```

Change the view slightly like this(adding data-id):

```
{% for post in tape %}
    ...
    {{ post.text }}
    ...
    <a href="/like_post/{{ post.id }}/" data-id="{{post.id}}">
        <img class="post-like"  src="{% static "" %}"/>
    </a>

     <span class="post-likes-count" {% if post.like.liked_users.count == 0 %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
                {{ post.like.liked_users.count }}
     </span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just keep one `if else` in span tag itself to `hide` the span if the count is 0, I am not experienced in python, so I guess you can edit the if else condition if it is wrong.

Comment: It does not change likes number. But link `/like_post/"+postlikescount.data().id+"/post_likes_count/` sends with post id, cool!

Comment: Can you add this `alert(JSON.stringify(data)); ` in success function of update likes count and tell me the output?

Comment: It tells the number of likes in alert. And number changes if click button time after time

Comment: Then change this `.html(data.count)` to `.html(data)`. Is `<span class="post-likes-count>"` present for the posts where likes count is 0.

Comment: Is `<span class="post-likes-count"></span>` present for the posts where likes count is 0. And how is the data present in data variable, is just the number

Comment: Not yet, I need to make a better view for this. I check if ajax works on post with 2 likes. So number can change from 1 to 2 and back.

Comment: And is the `<span class="post-likes-count"> tag` present immediately after the `a tag`? That can be the reason that the view is not updating. You can make it None then.

Comment: I mean this string `if like.liked_users.count == None` works not right so it does not send 0 yet :-)

Comment: Can you use the jquery block written above in the answer, I have updated it now. Just want to know what results you get?

Comment: Click on like button where, the count is more than 0.

Comment: In first alert I get `will show likes count [object Object]`; in second - class is undefined; in third - `will throw error1`. The third alert changing to `will throw error2` if there are 2 likes. I mean if 1 and click it shows `will throw error2` and then I reload page and number changing to 2.

Comment: Got that, the only error now is when there are *no likes* there is no `span tag` present on page, so it shows **class is undefined** in alert. So just to check please click on a like button where the count is already visible. You can check the updated code I have done slight change in `updateLikesCount()` function.

Comment: The number of likes before clicking was 1. After clicking: firs alert `class is undefined`; second alert `likes count 2`. Then reload page and number changing form 1 to 2.

Comment: Ahahahah if change `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count).show()` to `postlikescount.html(data.count)` ajax changes like button to the new number of likes XD

Comment: In the `.post-like` function I have kept this under success callback: `var like = img.parent();`. Was it not this which you had in your code? It was just one variable. which will not affect anything.

Comment: Nope. like button should stay. `class="post-likes-count"`(the span thing) should change.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current `jquery block` code?

Comment: In the current updated code, if you click on like it replaces the like button image with the likes count right?

Comment: Yes! And it is not even matter if there `.show()`in the end of `postlikescount.html(data.count)` or not. Same results.

Comment: I added show, thinking that the count is hidden initially. So is it the desired result that you are getting now?

Comment: Well, it is closer to it then I ever was. But I supposed to change number of likes, not like's image :-D Thanks a lot for your help. Think it would take couple to understand how to make it.

Comment: Can you remove the `if condition` around the span, and keep 0 as the value inside it, just for testing. And change it to this: `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count);`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, change `what`to this `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count)`?

Comment: Add this to `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count)` in the `updateLikesCount success function`.

Comment: If I only add `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count)` to success function, image still changes by clicking. If delete `postlikescount.html(data.count)` and add `postlikescount.next('.post-likes-count').html(data.count)` - nothing happens. Both ways nothing happens with number. – Kusko Andrew

Comment: If add ìn `updatePostLikesCount(postlikescount)     success function` `var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count")` all likes numbers on page changes to the like number of only one post (the first post's like I click). It change every time when like's image clicked. But it changes with ajax only likes's number, like's image stay.

Comment: What do you add and where? Can you post the html code of atleast 2 posts/tapes to see how the code appears once the page has loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115761/discussion-between-sahil-and-kusko-andrew).

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to improve this.

First ... you always want the html for the count to exist and should only hide it if there are no likes or show as zero. Otherwise you would need to add the html with javascript when first like is voted

Next

```
var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count");
```

This will include all elements with that class in the page .... not the specific one you want when you click the button.

Instead you could pass the one you want into `updatePostLikesCount()` as an argument

Change

```
function updatePostLikesCount(){
        var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count");
```

to

```
function updatePostLikesCount(postlikescount){
```

And in the click handler modify so we pass in the appropriate element

```
success: function() {
     // which count element
     var $countElement = img.next();
     // pass to function
     updatePostLikesCount($countElement);
}
```

Comment: Hi @charlietfl ! I added your code and it reload my whole page every time i click like button.

Comment: Probably error being thrown then in your browser console. Always look there first

Comment: yeah there is an error  
```ReferenceError: postlikescount is not defined```

Comment: Did you include the `<span class="post-likes-count" >` in page as I suggested at beginning?

Comment: Yes, it is there since beginning.

Comment: Sure you added the argument to the function? And passing element in when call function?

Comment: Oh...I see where it is it's before the `click`  when you call `updatePostLikesCount();` by itself. That shouldn't be needed

Comment: Also I can see the answer you deleted you didn't remove `var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count");`

Comment: I see another problem. You don't have url for the second request. You only need one request. Update the value in success of the request that fires when you click. Whole thing is more complicated than needed

Comment: Why do i need to delete things like ```var postlikescount = $(".post-likes-count");```? I got many posts n tape and every got it's id. And yes btw even if remove all in success i still can't send ```post.id```

Comment: Because your server code sets them all on page load then all you need to do is update the one that was clciked

Comment: Exactly I need to update one element and update it from view that count likes to class="post-likes-count". But before ajax must send a request to view. And view return back a number. If I put some code in success it does not really change situation. Because I do not refresh a part of element. Or possibly, I do not understand you at all.   :-(   Can you please write in code what do you mean?